# Limit of a function that I think is undefined

Tags: limits, wolfram-alpha

The $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, wolfram computes it to be $1$.

However the limit of $\ln(x)$ is infinity and $\sin(1/x)$ is $0$, the product of these are undefined, am I being stupid or is this wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole purpose of limits is to do away with indeterminate forms.

Comment: Yeah I seen ive been stupid,  this is just a subpart of the question, but this is the part thats confusing me, its a tiny part of it as well, i just dont know how to convert it to an appropriate form

Comment: Do you know L'Hôpital?

Comment: Huh. The limit is supposed to be 0 not 1, right?!

Comment: Really great answers guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\ln(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\, \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac1x}\to 0\cdot 1=0$$

thus

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: L'Hopital is a coward's way to go. Somewhere you learned $0<\sin u < u$ for small positive $u.$ Thus for large $x>0,$  $0 < (\ln x)\sin(1/x) < (\ln x)/x.$